# Drupal 6 CCK - Having a textbox appear when 'Other' is selected

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have a special content-type that I have created, and one of the fields is a radio button list.  The last element is named 'Other' and I would like to have a textbox appear and allow the user to enter in a non-defined value.

Is this sort of capability provided by any sort of module, or is this something that needs to be coded by hand?  (If so, would you mind pointing me in the correct direction?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The CCK Select Other](http://drupal.org/project/cck_select_other) module appears to get you most of the way there. I imagine it could be modified to work with radios fairly easily.

Comment: there is also 'Select or Other' http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other and 'Conditional Fields' http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields (i recommend this one).

Comment: @barraponto Can you put that in an answer so I can upvote you? Great info.

Comment: ..definitely nice but i like the extra functionality that barraponto suggests with 'select_or_other,' @barraponto, please put that in a separate answer!